# Requesting notification permission in unity not showing native dialog, auto declining

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

calling
`Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS", permissionCallbacks);` 
however the native dialog never appears, and the PermissionDenied callback is called. have deleted the app data and uninstalled so the permission hasn't been set. If i call the RegisterNotificationChannel the native dialog does appear...

```
var general = new AndroidNotificationChannel()
{
    // use the app id as the default ID
    Id = GeneralChannelId,
    Name = "General",
    Importance = Importance.High,
    Description = "General Game Notifications",
};
general.CanShowBadge = true;
general.EnableVibration = true;
    
AndroidNotificationCenter.RegisterNotificationChannel(general);
```

but i can't hook onto that native dialog to see there decision. Any help appreciated

target SDK set to latest installed (33)

tried calling `Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS", permissionCallbacks);`

expect a native dialog to appear, followed by a PermissionGranted or PermissionDenied callback depending on the choice.

dialog isn't appearing, permissionDenied being called.

Comment: Pretty sure you're supposed to set up the permissions in the Player Settings, not try to configure them yourself while running...

Comment: we're wanting to show a message before asking, explaining what the permission will be used for, and the option to deny and us not even ask for it. hence doing it in code, after they say okay to the message

Comment: Have you followed the docs?  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-RequestingPermissions.html
It says the permissions need to be in the app manifest first before you can ask.  Did you do that?

Comment: yeah its in the android manifest

Comment: @LukeTaylor did you manage to fix the issue? I have the same problem and my read/write external storage gets denied no matter what (after targeting android 33)